# Why doesn't the industry use my line?

Tags: transport-fever

I started a game with busses because getting a train line started is very expensive, but having earned a couple of million, I've now build a train line.
However the quarry on my train line won't produce stone, probably because the line is not in use. The other end of the track doesn't directly use stone, but that shouldn't matter. Since the Construction materials plant is very far downhill, trying to connect the line to a station there is huge pain, so I'm going to build a bus route there. I've had to sell my train because it was just losing money.
[image: Lowered configuration for screenshot of my station and the Quarry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're planning to just dump the stone somewhere? That's not going to work. You can force unload the stone at a station and transport the last bit by truck, though.

Comment: Changing to unload only makes no difference. I checked to make sure it's a goods station, not a passenger station. I don't have a bus line yet, but what's the point of making a bus line when there's no goods there? Wow, it actually detects whether there's a complete line. With the bus line in place it does start producing stone.

Answer (score 1):

The game does these things automatically after some time (one in-game month roughly). All your stations that are connected form a network and the game ensures that goods travel across it. You don't need to manually tell vehicles to dump goods at mid-points (like in old Transport Tycoon), the vehicles understand this and even sometimes pick alternative routes, if several are available.

You must however ensure the following:

- Station 1 is connected to the quarry. Looks ok from the screenshot.
- Station 2 is close enough to a truck station, with road between them.
- There's a train going on a line between the stations, with correct wagon types.
- There's a second **truck** station near the resource consumer, such as the construction materials plant, again with road between the station and the plant entrance.
- The produced goods by the plant are transported to another consumer.

Just as in the real world, stone is transported with trucks, not by bus. So obviously a bus line will do no good here, except for transporting stray workers to the plant (you won't get rich from that).

The quarry won't produce stone if you don't pick it up, but it also won't produce stone if there is no demand for it. The construction material plant only has a demand for stone, if there is a demand in turn for construction materials (view "potential" in the details tab of the plant's info window). And so on - in the end you'll have the consumers in a town.

When planning a new line, always start on the consumer side. Who will use the end product? And can you afford to build the whole supply chain needed?